# How to destructuring array when change value new array but old array not change

Tags: javascript

var a = [{a: '1'}, {a: '2'}, {a: '3'}];

var b = [...a];

b[0].a = 2;

console.log(a)

// result expect is b = [{a: '1'}, {a: '2'}, {a: '3'}];

// but real result is b = [{a: '2'}, {a: '2'}, {a: '3'}];

Answer (score 1):

You have to recreate all items in the new Array:

```
var b = a.map(i => { return { ...i } })
```

Comment: thanks too much ^^!

Comment: Why not `var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));`? Doesn't look like OP has functions inside `a`.

Comment: It works too, maybe more costly, lose some values (undefined, function, RegExp, Date, ...) but go deeper